# Admin Report_Grid or Widget_Grid bootstrap

Tags: adminhtml, grid, reports

Is anyone aware of a set of command-line tools that bootstrap Widget Grid or Report Grid code in the `Adminhtml` module? I know the following toolkits have a lot of amazing functionality, but nothing as a quick-start for backend views.

https://github.com/alistairstead/MageTool

https://github.com/dankocherga/MTool

https://github.com/classyllama/Wiz

Is there a generator or plugins available for some of these already amazing toolkits that ease this work? Any tips for this certain someone who is sick of copying Grid.php and forgetting to rename the class?

Thanks in advance - all feedback welcome.

Comment: Didn't even know about those tools. Thanks for the links.

Comment: I want to do stuff like this in magerun!!

Comment: Gosh, I never knew about magerun. There are easily a dozen of these types of tools!! Thanks @sparcksoft for that!

Comment: Yep there are definitely a handful.  I think magerun is one of the more active github projects currently at least - hopefully it will continue to be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is even online version of Magento Module Creator, by silksoftware. It has lots of options!

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

I don't guarantee it as I personally have never used it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This is insanity!!! Great find! The boilerplate code for backend modules and even a GRID VIEW GENERATOR is fantastic - I wish there were a cli version where we could define existing namespaces - in much the same fashion that Mage_Tool does.

Comment: Accepting this and awarding the bounty, mainly because no other tool seems to offer this kind of functionality - however it really doesn't suit my needs exactly. I still have to harvest out the grid code, updating namespaces, etc. But I see this as a fantastic starting point for new modules. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moduleCreator](https://github.com/tzyganu/moduleCreator) (magento module to generate backend modules, with quite alot of functionality)

Comment: Looks like an interesting tool, but seems to be broken on installation - ajax data loads in the tab navigation. I will watch this product for future dev but it's definitely not mature enough just yet.

Comment: FYI, I entered an issue into the github issue tracker for this - perhaps we can get it fixed quickly. I'd like to review the backend module functionality before accepting your answer.

Comment: @philwinkle i've email the author.  works fine on my end, Magento 1.7.0.2, not tested on other versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Magicento](http://www.magicento.com) the last version has an action to create Grid and Forms (http://magicento.com/#features) and I will add more features related to that in the next releases.